# Clang Format Objective-C Methods with Newlines

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, clang-format

I'm using clang-format to format my code via [Travis Jeffery's project](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode). I'm working on a custom .clang-format setup to fit our style guides. One thing I can't figure out is how to take a long method name like the following.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithSqliteStoreURL:nil managedObjectModelURL:nil managedObjectModelClasses:nil];
}
```

And format it to look like the following. This is what I would like it to look like.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithSqliteStoreURL:nil
                  managedObjectModelURL:nil
              managedObjectModelClasses:nil];
}
```

When I apply the Google style recommendation, I get the following, which is not what I want it to look like.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    return
        [self initWithSqliteStoreURL:nil managedObjectModelURL:nil managedObjectModelClasses:nil];
}
```

This adheres to our column width needs, but doesn't fit our internal style guide. I can't figure out what combo of clang-format flags I need to achieve my goal. Any insight would be appreciated.